# How to trigger a rule on entering a room in inform7

Tags: inform7

I'm trying to trigger the end of the game if the player enters a room with an object (their phone) "charged".

I must just not understand the syntax for triggering a rule on entering a location, as I realized that my other similar rules are also not occurring.

I have:

```
Instead of entering Great Hall:
    if phone is charged:
         say "Hooray you win.";
```

but rules like:

```
Instead of entering Big house:
    If butler is in big house:
         say "'blah blah blah";
         now player is in big house;
    otherwise:
         say "Oh no, can't get into the house.";
```

Also are not working. I read section 9.4 on ending play, have replaced my instead with after and before as well, with no luck. How do I do something after a player enters a room under conditions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The entering action is triggered when entering things like containers, supporters and doors. For rooms you'll want "going to".

```
After going to the Great Hall when the phone is charged:
    end the story saying "Hooray you win."
```

It's also better, instead of moving the player manually, to let the library handle transitioning between rooms whenever possible which is what `continue the action` does here:

```
Instead of going to the Big House:
    If the butler is in the Big House:
         say "'blah blah blah'";
         continue the action;
    otherwise:
         say "Oh no, can't get into the house."
```